# What does "Separate source and build directories" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx for the first time. I am running `sphinx-quickstart`, but don't understand the first question being asked:

```
> Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]:
```

What does this mean? What difference does it make whether these directories are separated or not? How do I know which one to choose?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put simply the option *"Separate sources from build"* of the [`sphinx-quickstart`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-quickstart.html) tool leads to 2 possible directory/file structure layouts:

1. If you choose "Yes" (to separate), you 'll get one `build` directory and one `source` directory:

   The generated `.rst` files and `conf.py` are placed in the `source` directory (afterwards any `.rst` files you write should also be placed there). The final documentation files (HTML for example) that Sphinx will generate from the reStructuredText source files are placed in the `build` directory.

   ```
   C:.
   │   make.bat
   │   Makefile
   │
   ├───build
   └───source
       │   conf.py
       │   index.rst
       │
       ├───_static
       └───_templates
   ```

   Here's an excerpt of running the `sphinx-quickstart` tool choosing "YES" to separate sources from build:

   ```
   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\source\conf.py.
   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\source\index.rst.
   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\Makefile.
   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\make.bat.

   Finished: An initial directory structure has been created.
   ```
2. If you choose "No" (to not separate), the `source` directory is not created so the contents that were placed in the `source` directory choosing the "separate sources" option will instead be placed in the base directory from where you run `sphinx-quickstart`.

   Also the build directory will be slightly different now having an underscore `_build` in the name:

   ```
   C:.
   │   conf.py
   │   index.rst
   │   make.bat
   │   Makefile
   │
   ├───_build
   ├───_static
   └───_templates
   ```

   Here's an excerpt of running the `sphinx-quickstart` tool choosing "NO" to separate sources from build:

   ```
   Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: 

   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\conf.py.
   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\index.rst.
   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\Makefile.
   Creating file C:\Your_Project\docs\make.bat.

   Finished: An initial directory structure has been created.
   ```

> How do I know which one to choose?

The prevalent option I've seen is choosing to separate `sources` from `build`. Keeping the files separate arguably makes things more organized in larger projects. The only drawback is that you'll have more directories, which may seem confusing at first, but the increased separation tends to be worth it in the long run.